# $E \in \tau$ if and only if $\tau_{E}= \{A \in \tau | A \subseteq E\}$

Tags: general-topology

I am having trouble proving this proposition:

Let $ (X, \tau)$ be a topological space and $E \subseteq X$

Prove that $E \in \tau$  if and only if $\tau_{E}= \{A \in \tau |  A \subseteq  E\}$
 where $\tau_{E} $ is the induced topology.

In my lecture notes, the induced topology over a subset E of X is defined as 
$\tau_{E}= \{A \cap E |  A \in  \tau\} $

Intuitively, it's clear what the proposition says, if E is an open set of $\tau$ then the induced topology is formed of the open subsets of $\tau$ included in E, I just can't figure how to formally write the prove.
I would really appreciate some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two implications:

First, suppose $E \in \tau$. We need to show that $\tau_E = \{A\in \tau: A \subseteq E\}$ which is two inclusions: If $A \in \tau_E$ then by definition of $\tau_E$, $A = A'\cap E$ for some $A' \in \tau$. As *also* $E \in \tau$ we thus see that $A=A'\cap E \in \tau$ too (finite intersection), and $A = A' \cap E \subseteq E$ is trivial so $A \in \{A\in \tau: A \subseteq E\}$. On the other had if $A \in \{A\in \tau: A \subseteq E\}$ we can just write $A= A \cap E$ (as $A \subseteq E$) and see that we have written $A$ as an intersection of a member of $\tau$ (namely $A$) intersected with $E$, so $A \in \tau_E$. This inclusion shows the equality and the left to right implication.

Now suppose $\tau_E = \{A\in \tau: A \subseteq E\}$ and we want to see that $E \in \tau$. This is trivial now, as $E = E \cap X$ and $X \in \tau$ and so $E \in \tau_E$ always but then $E \in \{A\in \tau: A \subseteq E\}$ which by definition means that $E \in \tau$. Hence the right to left implication has also been shown and hence the equivalence.

Comment: Perfect! Just as a side thing, I have a doubt... I was trying to do the prove by contradiction , but when I start by  negating E∈τ, can I imply E is an closed set? or not necessarily?, that is , in general if a subset of X is not an open set, then is it a closed set, or could be neither?.  For example in the real numbers with the euclidean topology, (a,b] is neither closed nor open, but in general topological spaces, without metric I am not sure

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver working from the negation is not a good idea. A set not in the topology need not be closed it can be very wild. You don’t get a lot of info from $E\notin \tau$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $E=X\cap E\in \tau_E$ by definition of induced topology.

($\Leftarrow$) So, if $\tau_E=\{A\in \tau\mid\ A\subseteq E\}$ it follows that, in particular, $E\in \tau$, since for $E$ to belong to the right hand side must satisfy the first condition.

($\Rightarrow$) Conversely, if $E\in \tau$. then $E\cap A\in \tau$ for all $A\in \tau$. Therefore, $\{A\in \tau\mid\ A\subseteq E\}=\{A\cap E\mid\ A\in\tau\}=\tau_E$.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't get it "E∈τ, since for E to belong to the right hand side must satisfy the first condition"... get you be explicit? and in the last part , how exactly can I justify the equallity of the two sets?

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver If you assume that $\tau_E=\{A\in\tau\mid A\subseteq E\}$ and since $E$ is always an element of $\tau_E$. Then the equality tells you that it is also an element of the set in the right. So, $E$ must satisfy that $E\in \tau$ and $E\subseteq E$. In particular, $E\in \tau$.

Comment: @ cardinalRed ok  that's clear... in the second part , $\{A∈τ∣ A⊆E\}=\{A∩E∣ A∈τ\}$, I don't get it ,how do I justify it? Maybe by proving they include each other